# Console Access -- how does this work?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, console, tty

My dedicated provider did the following:

```
wget S03HvTechAccess > /dev/null 2>&1
mv S03HvTechAccess /etc/rc3.d/ > /dev/null 2>&1
chmod 755 /etc/rc3.d/S03HvTechAccess > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and it shows:

```
/usr/bin/openvt -c 8 /bin/bash
```

What is openvt? It mentions you can login without a password. How does that work in terms of how do you connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

`openvt` starts a command on a new virtual console. The command will use the STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR from the new virtual console.

Comment: A virtual console isn't a pty, is it?

Comment: Yes, Linux virtual console has is mapped to a pty device. It is the one that you can see on the physical server by pressing ALT+F1... or CTRL+ALT+F1... when in X.

Comment: Have a look at /dev/pts. There are no mapped ptys for /dev/vcs[1-6]. There are technical differences. Thus AFAIK vcs are not called ptys.

Answer (score 0):

This command starts a root shell on the physical console of the server. There can be multiple virtual console sessions on the physical console - this uses virtual console number 8 (that's the "-c 8"). 
Because this is just a shell, rather than a login process, if someone has physical access to the console they get root access without needing a password.